# Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

Somebody knows why Xcode 5 Analyze complains about this:

> ZIFollowerRequestsCell.m:34:5: Returning 'self' while it is not set to
>   the result of '[(super or self) init...]'

```
#import "ZIFollowerRequestsCell.h"

@implementation ZIFollowerRequestsCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ZIFollowerRequestsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

        self.profileImageView.image = nil;
        self.profileImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   }
   return self;
}

@end

@interface ZIFollowerRequestsCell : UITableViewCell <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this class inherit from some other class?

Comment: It complains because you are supposed to assign the return value of `[super init]` to `self`.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri yes, it's a UITableViewCell object.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, but I don't know why it doesn't load the nib, so I try getting it using -loadNibNamed:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning self twice. The second time, well, what Xcode said. Also, it's good practice not to use `self.variable` in the constructor, just use `_variable`.

Did you register your cell? Assuming you have a ZIFollowerRequestsCell.xib whose root view is a cell with class ZIFollowerRequestsCell, try this in your view controller:

```
NSString * const REUSE_ID_CELL = @"ZIFollowerRequestsCell";

- (void)registerNIBs
{
    NSBundle *classBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[ZIFollowerRequestsCell class]];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:REUSE_ID_CELL bundle:classBundle];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:topNib forCellReuseIdentifier:REUSE_ID_CELL];
}

- (NSString *)reuseIdentifierForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return REUSE_ID_CELL; 
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *reuseID = [self reuseIdentifierForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseID];
    return cell; 
}
```